# how to load library in android,with jni support

Tags: android, makefile, java-native-interface, android-ndk

i have two libs, but there is a dependency between the two libs, such as:

B.a  depends on A.a

but to build a shared lib C.so( B.a => C.so ), what should i do. here is my Android.mk,

LOCAL_LDFLAGS += $(LOCAL_PATH)/B.a

but after ndk-building, it comes up the errors, undefined reference..functions.(the functions are all defined in A.a)

does that mean, it can not load A.a?

is it necessary to load A.a in Android.mk again?

Comment: It means the linker cannot find A.a

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look at my answer for this similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11193831/904134)

Your problem is the usage of `LOCAL_LDFLAGS` which is limited to a specific set of libraries, depending on the api level you are using. Be sure to make use of the provided ndk documentation in `$NDK/docs/`, specifically `$NDK/docs/ANDROID-MK.html` and `$NDK/docs/STABLE-APIS.html` to find out how to properly write your Android.mk file.