# Android NDK building - Include LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm having problems building a project under the Android NDK. Most likely its due to the proper shared / static libraries not being included. The ones as -lsomeLib I added, but the ones as LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES are not being included it seems...

My Android.mk contains the following

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libutils libmedia libz libbinder

1. Where does ndk-build actually look for these libraries?
2. If I don't include the -lutils -lmedia -lz -lbinder, I am not able to even get to the linker error. I have a feeling including just -LsomeDir and -lsomeLib is not the correct way to add them.

Here is the complete Android.mk.

```
LOCAL_PATH := /Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/videoplayer/jni
LIBPLAYER_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../LibPlayer

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

$(warning Android make file: $(LOCAL_PATH)/Android.mk)
$(warning Android sysroot: $(SYSROOT))
$(warning Additional LD_LIBS: $(LOCAL_PATH)/lib)

ifeq ($(BUILD_ID),MID)
        LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DENABLE_FREE_SCALE
endif

LOCAL_MODULE    := libamplayerjni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_farcore_playerservice_AmPlayer.c sys_conf.c
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LIBPLAYER_PATH)/amplayer/player/include \
    $(LIBPLAYER_PATH)/amplayer/control/include \
    $(LIBPLAYER_PATH)/amcodec/include \
    $(LIBPLAYER_PATH)/amffmpeg \
    $(JNI_H_INCLUDE) \
    /Android/ndk/build/tools/android-9-toolchain/sysroot/usr/include \
    /Android/ndk/build/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include \
    /Android/source_2.3/system/core/include \
    /Android/source_2.3/frameworks/base/include

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/videoplayer/jni/lib -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog -lz -lm -ldl **-lmedia -lstagefright -lutils -lbinder -lgcc -landroid -lc -lstdc++ -lthread_db**

**LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libamplayer libamcodec libavformat libavcodec libavutil libamadec**
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libutils libmedia libz libbinder 

LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := false

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

One of many errors related specifically to those libraries (ie libmedia.so).

```
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/videoplayer/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libamadec.a(android_out.o): In function `android_uninit':
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/LibPlayer/amadec/audio_out/android_out.cpp:220: undefined reference to `android::AudioTrack::stop()'
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/LibPlayer/amadec/audio_out/android_out.cpp:228: undefined reference to `android::AudioTrack::~AudioTrack()'
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/videoplayer/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libamadec.a(android_out.o): In function `~Autolock':
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks to me like you should not be including `-lmedia` etc in your `LOCAL_LDLIBS` arguments.

### 1. Where does ndk-build actually look for these libraries?

If you look in `$NDK/docs/STABLE-APIS.html` you will see that there is a specified set of libraries you can include in this manner. Note:

> `The headers corresponding to a given API level are now located under $NDK/platforms/android-<level>/arch-arm/usr/include`

Having looked myself, none of the libraries you specified exist there, although I only looked for API-14.

---

### 2. If I don't include the -lutils -lmedia -lz -lbinder, I am not able to even get to the linker error. I have a feeling including just -LsomeDir and -lsomeLib is not the correct way to add them.

If your libraries are just regular c/c++ libraries that you would `#include` you should use `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` instead.

Also note, from `$NDK/docs/ANDROID-MK.html`:

> - The build system handles many details for you. For example, you
>     don't need to list header files or explicit dependencies between
>     generated files in your Android.mk. The NDK build system will
>     compute these automatically for you.

In order to use other libraries in my native code, I simply `#include` it and then specify where to find the headers. Here's my `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES`:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/shared/Core/inc \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/shared/Model/inc  \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/shared/boost/include
```

I hope this helps.