# Android ndk + libgdx

Tags: android-ndk, libgdx

I have a project in libgdx. I want to add Native Support.
When connecting libgdx folder libs are files 
**\ armeabi \ libgdx.so 

\ armeabi \ libandroidgl20.so 

\ armeabi-v7a \ libgdx.so

\ armeabi-v7a \ libandroidgl20.so**

When I build the libraries **My.cpp**, folders **armeabi** and **armeabi-v7a** overwritten
**armeabi** folder contains only **My.so**, folder **armeabi-v7a** becomes empty.
An error occurs.

my file *Android.mk*

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := My
### Add all source file names to be included in lib separated by a whitespace
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := My.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I know that modify Android.mk, but all my attempts failed.
Please tell me how to fix it.

Answer (score 7):

The way that works for me after Eclipse Android tools' "add native support" in an already started project (that messed up the thing and removes libgdx's so files after each rebuild).

1.- Make a subdir structure inside "jni" folder to put libgdx's shared libs

- jni

  - shared

    - libgdx

      - armeabi

        - libandroidgl20.so
        - ligdx.so
      - armeabi-v7a

        - libandroidgl20.so
        - libgdx.so
  - Android.mk
  - Application.mk
  - my_app.cpp

2.- Add the following lines to Android.mk after "LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)"

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := gdx
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := shared/libgdx/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libgdx.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := androidgl20
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := shared/libgdx/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libandroidgl20.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

3.- Add the following lines to Application.mk (if this file doesn't exists, create one in the same folder as Android.mk)

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
APP_MODULES := my_app gdx androidgl20
```

And that's all, folks!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to explicitly enable both architectures. Create a file `Application.mk` with the following line:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
```

You'll also need to reference the libraries for the linking. Add the following to Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libgdx libandroidgl20
```

Second, you need to make the third party libraries available for the build. The guidance is here: [Android NDK building - Include LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987767/android-ndk-building-include-local-shared-libraries)